# Application thread in JVM

Tags: jvm

When JVM runs our program (let's say the most simple program like Hello World) it starts an application thread for it. And, my question is: What exactly is executed in that thread? Is it a bytecode interpreter executing our program? We can assume that our program wasn't JITed.

Comment: You already answered it yourself. Do you also have a real question?

Answer (score 0):

> it starts an application thread for it.

The JVM is a program and when it is started, it must have at least one thread to run anything. As such the JVM doesn't need to start the first thread.

> What exactly is executed in that thread?

This depends on the JVM. For example https://www.excelsiorjet.com/ precompiles the code before you start the program, so it is already in native code.  The Oracle JVM only compiles the code once it has been run enough, which for a hello world is unlikely.

> We can assume that our program wasn't JITed

You can't assume that code has or has not been JIT'ed nor can you assume that just because it has been JIT-ed now that it won't be recompiled later i.e. it can fall back to interpreter mode in some cases.

Comment: The parameter Xint with jvm can make sure the java run with interpreter,not with jit.